# Too low psrf values in runjags summary?

Tags: r, jags, runjags

Runjags is reporting very low `psrf = 1.0047` for a chain that apparently has convergence problems:

[image]

```
> print(o, vars = "q_date2")

JAGS model summary statistics from 3000 samples (chains = 3; adapt+burnin = 1000):

         Lower95   Median   Upper95      Mean       SD    MCerr MC%ofSD SSeff    AC.10   psrf
q_date2 -0.17611 -0.10467 0.0053844 -0.087376 0.063296 0.023726    37.5     7 0.022495 1.0047
```

When I try to compute the `psrf` using coda, I get a result which looks much more reasonable:

```
> gelman.diag(as.mcmc.list(o)[,'q_date2'], transform=FALSE, autoburnin=FALSE)
Potential scale reduction factors:

     Point est. Upper C.I.
[1,]       3.54       7.94
```

So why is the `psrf` reported by runjags so low? Is it a problem of runjags, or am I doing something wrong?

I use current version of runjags (1.2.1-0) in R 3.1.0.

EDIT: during creating summaries I got warnings - sorry for not mentioning them before:

```
Warning messages:
1: In autocorrs[x$stochastic] <- x$autocorr[4, ] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
2: In psrfs[x$stochastic] <- x$psrf$psrf[, 1] :
  number of items to replace is not a multiple of replacement length
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears (from information sent to me off-line) that the psrf is being calculated correctly, but is being reported out of sequence because some information is not available for some semi-stochastic monitored variables. The fact that this isn't being picked up by the software is a bug that I will fix!

In the meantime, you can either (a) ignore the psrf listed in the output for summary() and use RJout$psrf (or your own code) instead, or (b) remove the monitored variables (M in this case) that are causing the problem. The development version of runjags has even better solutions (summary statistics and plots are (re-)calculated after the model has been returned), and should be on CRAN in the next couple of months.

This is also a good reminder that manual checking of trace plots is an essential part of MCMC analysis :)

Comment: Thanks! And actually, if I run `gelman.diag` on the MCMC with the `M` variable, i.e. `gelman.diag(as.mcmc.list(outRJ))`, it will say *"Error in chol.default(W) : the leading minor of order 1 is not positive definite"*. So this is probably the reason why this problem occured!